# Mongodb tailable cursor - Isn't that bad practice to have a continually spinning loop?

Tags: mongodb, publish-subscribe

I'm looking into the best way to have my app get notified when a collection is updated in mongo. From everything I read on the interwebs, the standard practice is to use a capped collection with a tailable cursor and [here's](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) a snippet from mongodb's docs on tailable cursors.

I notice in there snippet that they have a continuous `while` loop that never stops. Doesn't this seem like a bad practice? I can't imagine this would perform well when scaling.

Does anyone have any insight as to how this could possibly scale and still be performant? Is there something i'm not understanding?

**EDIT**

So [this](http://jpaljasma.blogspot.com/2013/11/howto-mongodb-tailable-cursors-in-nodejs.html) is a good example where i see the stream is just open and since the stream is never closed, it just has a listener listening. That makes sense to me i guess.

I'm also looking at [this](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub/blob/master/lib/channel.js#L131) mubsub implementation where they use a `setTimeout` with 1 second pause.

Aren't these typically bad practices - to leave a stream open or to use a setTimeout like that? Am i just being old school?

Comment: Did you consider to have whatever other app is updating the collection to notify the app directly instead of going the detour over MongoDB (which isn't designed for this)?

Comment: Yes i have considered that and I don't want the app that is updating mongo to have custom code for my one app. If anything i'd use a message queue, but i'm just exploring options at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

> I notice in there snippet that they have a continuous while loop that never stops. Doesn't this seem like a bad practice?

Looks like it to me as well, yes.

> Does anyone have any insight as to how this could possibly scale and still be performant?

You can [set the `AwaitData` flag](http://shtylman.com/post/the-tail-of-mongodb/) and [make the `more()` call blocking](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) for some time - it won't block until data is available though, but it will block for some time. Requires server support (from v. 1.6 or so) That is also what's being done in the node.js example you posted (`{awaitdata:true}`).

> where they use a `setTimeout` with 1 second pause.

The way I read it, they retry to get the cursor back when lost in regular intervals and return an error iff that failed for a full second.

> Aren't these typically bad practices - to leave a stream open [...]?

You're not *forgetting* the stream (that would be bad), you keep using it - that's pretty much the definition of a tailable cursor.